# Xamarin.Forms Swipe to change between CollectionViews

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi there:) So that's my problem:
I've got two CollectionViews in my app and I want to be able to change between them by swiping side to side. Is there a good way to implement this?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please show some code. What did you already try to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can try to put the two CollectionViews in two Contentpages and set the two pages as the TabbedPage's child page. Then you can try to select different ColectionView by selecting different page when user swipes on the screen. For more information, you can check the official document about the [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page).

In addition, I suggest you use the Community Toolkit's control named [TabView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview), because it can put the two CollectionViews in the same page and there is a [sample](https://github.com/chaosifier/TabView) on the github, you can refer to it.